# How to scrape all ufc fighters and not repeat only the first fighter?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am making a program to scrape UFC fighters' names and info using `BeautifulSoup`. I am using a `for-loop` iterating through the `div` holding this info scraping specific information.

The issue I am having is when printing the data only the first name is repeated as well as not displaying the correct amount of names. It repeats the name around ten times while there are definitely more than 11 names.

Current Code:

```
from cgitb import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

html_text = requests.get('https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
fighters = soup.find_all('div', class_ = ("node node--type-athlete node--view-mode-all- 
athletes-result ds-1col clearfix"))
for fighter in enumerate(fighters, 1):
    fighter_name = soup.find('span', class_ = ("c-listing-athlete__name")).text.replace("_", 
" ")
    fighter_nickname = soup.find('div', class_ = ("field field--name-nickname field--type-string field--label-hidden")).text
    fighter_weight_class = soup.find('div', class_ = ("field field--name-stats-weight-class field--type-entity-reference field--label-hidden field__items")).text
    fighter_ufc_record = soup.find('span', class_ = ("c-listing-athlete__record")).text
    print(f'''Fighter Name: {fighter_name.strip()}''')
    print("************************")
```

output:

```
fighter Name: Asjabharan
************************
Fighter Name: Asjabharan
************************
Fighter Name: Asjabharan
************************
Fighter Name: Asjabharan
************************
Fighter Name: Asjabharan
************************
Fighter Name: Asjabharan
************************
Fighter Name: Asjabharan
************************
Fighter Name: Asjabharan
************************
Fighter Name: Asjabharan
************************
Fighter Name: Asjabharan
************************
Fighter Name: Asjabharan
************************
```

When printing "fighter" I get all the data but I'm not able to manipulate the data neatly.

Comment: Inside the for loop you're doing `soup.find(...)`, which searches the whole html from the top, so you find the same first fighter every time.  I think you meant to do `fighter.find(...)`, so you only search the html for that fighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have to use fighters in lieu of  enumerate(fighters, 1) and fighter instead of soup

```
from cgitb import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

html_text = requests.get('https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
fighters = soup.find_all('div', class_ = ("node node--type-athlete node--view-mode-all-athletes-result ds-1col clearfix"))
for fighter in fighters:
    fighter_name = fighter.find('span', class_ = ("c-listing-athlete__name")).text.replace("_", " ")
    fighter_nickname = fighter.find('div', class_ = ("field field--name-nickname field--type-string field--label-hidden"))
    fighter_nickname = fighter_nickname.text if fighter_nickname else None
    fighter_weight_class = fighter.find('div', class_ = ("field field--name-stats-weight-class field--type-entity-reference field--label-hidden field__items")).text
    fighter_ufc_record = fighter.find('span', class_ = ("c-listing-athlete__record")).text
    print(f'''Fighter Name: {fighter_name.strip()}''')
    print("************************")
```

**Output:**

```
Fighter Name: Asjabharan
************************
Fighter Name: Angga -
************************
Fighter Name: Danny Abbadi
************************
Fighter Name: Nariman Abbassov
************************
Fighter Name: Tank Abbott
************************
Fighter Name: Hamdy Abdelwahab
************************
Fighter Name: Shamil Abdurakhimov
************************
Fighter Name: Daichi Abe
************************
Fighter Name: Papy Abedi
************************
Fighter Name: Ricardo Abreu
************************
Fighter Name: Klidson Abreu
************************
```

Answer (score 0):

> issue I am having is when printing the data only the first name is repeated

As mentioned use `fighter.find(...)` inside your `for-loop` instead of `soup.find(...)` to focus your search to the html for the fighter only.

> It repeats the name around ten times while there are definitely more than 11 names.

Issue here is, that *more data* is loaded via `ajax`, so you have to simulate these calls to get more then just the first 11.

##### Example

**Note:** *Starts at page 245 to show that while loop stops if there is no more data available, simply change it to **0** to start from first page.*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {
    'view_name': 'all_athletes',
    'page': 1,
    'view_path':'/athletes/all',
    'view_display_id': 'page',
    'gender': 'All',
    'page': 245,
    '_drupal_ajax': 1
}

data = []

while True:
    r = requests.post('https://www.ufc.com/views/ajax?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax',headers=headers, data=payload)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.json()[3]['data'])

    fighters = soup.select('.view-items-wrp li:has(div.c-listing-athlete-flipcard__inner)')
    for fighter in fighters:
        data.append({
            'fighter_name': fighter.find('span', class_ = ("c-listing-athlete__name")).get_text(strip=True).replace("_", " ") if fighter.find('span', class_ = ("c-listing-athlete__name")) else None,
            'fighter_nickname': fighter.find('div', class_ = ("field field--name-nickname")).get_text(strip=True) if fighter.find('div', class_ = ("field field--name-nickname")) else None,
            'fighter_weight_class': fighter.find('div', class_ = ("field--name-stats-weight-class")).get_text(strip=True) if fighter.find('div', class_ = ("field--name-stats-weight-class")) else None,
            'fighter_ufc_record': fighter.find('span', class_ = ("c-listing-athlete__record")).get_text(strip=True) if fighter.find('span', class_ = ("c-listing-athlete__record")) else None,
        })

    if not fighters:
        break
    else:
        payload['page'] = payload['page']+1
        print(payload['page'])

data
```

##### Output

```
[{'fighter_name': 'Emmanuel Yarbrough',
  'fighter_nickname': None,
  'fighter_weight_class': None,
  'fighter_ufc_record': '0-0-0 (W-L-D)'},
 {'fighter_name': 'Cale Yarbrough',
  'fighter_nickname': None,
  'fighter_weight_class': 'Middleweight',
  'fighter_ufc_record': '0-1-0 (W-L-D)'},
 {'fighter_name': 'Ashley Yoder',
  'fighter_nickname': None,
  'fighter_weight_class': "Women's Strawweight",
  'fighter_ufc_record': '8-8-0 (W-L-D)'},
 {'fighter_name': 'Sang Hoon Yoo',
  'fighter_nickname': None,
  'fighter_weight_class': 'Lightweight',
  'fighter_ufc_record': '0-0-0 (W-L-D)'},...]
```

Comment: How were you able to figure out that there were 245 pages? sorry, this code is confusing to me since I don't know it but thanks for introducing me to ajax, I had no idea. Did you find that post URL through the networking tab in the developer tool?

Comment: i saw that everytime time i would click "loadmore" that POST URL would come up

Comment: Saw you already figured out how to find the post request in the dev tools , great. There are more then 245 pages, this was only to show up that the while loop will stop at the end. An example do not need to iterate all the results.  Set the number to zero and it will endup by 2727 ATHLETES / 11 ATHLETS per Page -> 247 Pages and should fit your needs